# I just went back in time

Tags: ruby, time, clock, cpu-architecture

I went 14 seconds in the past(using Ruby, in my IRB console). I just wanted to understand what happened exactly.

I was just observing the return value of `Time.now.strftime('%F %T')` (returns a string formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") by evaluating it almost every seconds.
But then, this happened :

[image: weird back in time]

Time jumped from "2018-07-18 14:25:25" to "2018-07-18 14:25:11"... No context, no Timecop (Ruby library that permit to go back in time), just Ruby and Time (a Ruby core library to manage time).

What could happened here ? Could this ever happen again ?

Comment: maybe the world went back 14 secs ... :)

Comment: Your computer's time was running fast and resynced with NTP? Could this happen again? Sure, do not expect your computer's time to increment only.

Comment: I agree the obvious and most likely reason is that time itself shifted 14 seconds. It is really the only the logical conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely your operating system just synched with an NTP server and actually "physically" set back its clock. You were lucky enough to catch it in the act.

> Could this happen again [..]?

Yes, something like this can happen at any moment. [Falsehood #33 that programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time):

> Timestamps always advance monotonically.

Comment: ...And in case it's not clear enough: This has almost certainly got nothing to do with ruby, and everything to do with the computer it's running on.

Comment: @TomLord: Other languages may provide multiple clock functions,   e.g. [POSIX `clock_gettime(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) provides `CLOCK_REALTIME` (current system time) as well as `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (time since an unspecified starting point, useful for timing intervals).  I don't know of a monotonic clock that you could use as time-of-day, though.  The solution to that problem is to use a better NTP setup on your computer that slows down your clock to get back in sync instead of making jumps, although for large offsets you would want to jump anyway.